# JPA Spring Boot Hibernate Rest API: Why does Hibernate delete before when insert into?

Tags: angular, spring-boot, hibernate, rest, jpa

The following scenario I would like to describe:
I use Spring Boot as a backend, a MySQL database and Angular 9 as frontend.

It is a ManyToMany relationship between employees and booking.

**MySQL**

employees:

| emp_id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | test |

booking:

| book_id | attribute |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | test |

book_emp:

| emp_id | book_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |

Everything works fine so far but when I post further values to the linked table, all other tuples are deleted.

book_emp:

| emp_id | book_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |

This is how the result should be:

| emp_id | book_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |

**Console**

```
Hibernate: insert into booking (hours, total, wadge_eur, year) values (?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: delete from book_emp where emp_id=?
Hibernate: insert into book_emp (emp_id, book_id) values (?, ?)
```

Why Hibernate delete from book_emp? I have already tried all possible variants in the classes for the ManyToMany annotation. Unfortunately without success. I think the problem is with the RestController.

I tried PUT before, but the same result as POST.

**Spring Boot**
Employee.java

```
@ManyToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.ALL }, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = Constant.BOOK_EMP, joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = Constant.EMP_ID, referencedColumnName = Constant.EMP_ID), 
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = Constant.BOOK_ID, referencedColumnName = Constant.BOOK_ID), 
            uniqueConstraints = {
            @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = { Constant.EMP_ID, Constant.BOOK_ID }) 
            })
    @JsonBackReference(value = Constant.BOOKING)
    private Set<Booking> bookings;
```

Booking.java

```
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "bookings")
       private Set<Employee> employees;
```

EmployeeController.java:

```
@PostMapping(Constant.EMPLOYEE + "/{id}")
    public Employee postEmployeeById(@PathVariable(value = "id") Long employeeId,
            @Valid @RequestBody Employee employeeDetails) throws ResourceNotFoundException {
        Employee employee = employeeRepository.findById(employeeId)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFoundException("Employee not found for this id ::" + employeeId));
                
        employee.setBookings(employeeDetails.getBookings());
                
        return employeeRepository.save(employee);
```

EmployeeRepository.java

```
@Repository
public interface EmployeeRepository extends JpaRepository<Employee, Long> {}
```

**Angular**
employee.service.ts

```
  updateEmployeeData(id: number, value: any): Observable<Object> {
    return this.httpClient.post(`${this.baseURL + this.empURL}/${id}`, value);
  }
```

How can I tell Hibernate to stop deleting?

Comment: But this is what you ask it to do: `employee.setBookings(employeeDetails.getBookings());`. It first has to delete old associations before applying the new ones.

Comment: and what i should to ask instead?

Comment: Well, it seem your collection of bookings gets updated in the client side. So in this case, booking with id 1 gets deleted so you're only left with booking 2.

Answer (score 0):

**[Resolution]**

Employee Class

```
//LOMBOK 
...
@EqualsAndHashCode(exclude = "bookings")
...

    @ManyToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.ALL }, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
        @JoinTable(name = Constant.BOOK_EMP, joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = 
         Constant.EMP_ID, referencedColumnName = Constant.EMP_ID, updatable = false, 
         insertable = false), 
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = Constant.BOOK_ID, referencedColumnName = Constant.BOOK_ID, updatable = false, insertable = false), 
            uniqueConstraints = {
            @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = { Constant.EMP_ID, Constant.BOOK_ID }) 
            })
    @JsonBackReference(value = Constant.BOOKING)
    private Set<Booking> bookings;
    
    @JsonIgnore
    public boolean addEmpBook(Set<Booking> set) {
            return this.bookings.addAll(set);           
    }
```

Booking Class

```
//LOMBOK: 
...
@EqualsAndHashCode(exclude = "employees")
...
    
    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "bookings")
    private Set<Employee> employees;
```

EmployeeController

```
    @PostMapping(Constant.EMPLOYEE + "/{id}")
    public Employee postEmployeeById(@PathVariable(value = "id") Long employeeId,
            @Valid @RequestBody Employee employeeDetails) throws ResourceNotFoundException {
        Employee employee = employeeRepository.findById(employeeId)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFoundException("Employee not found for 
                this id ::" + employeeId));
        
        employee.addEmpBook(employeeDetails.getBookings());
        return employeeRepository.save(employee);
    }
```

console Hibernate

```
Hibernate: insert into booking (hours, total, wadge_eur, year) values (?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into book_emp (emp_id, book_id) values (?, ?)
```